# Excel sheet with discount based on total amount with discount intervals

Tags: excel, vba, intervals, discount

I am in the process of making an Excel spreadsheet and I need to calculate a discount based on the total amount.

There will be 2 (3 if you count no discount) discount levels.
For instance:
$0-$1000 gives 0% discount
$1001-$2000 gives 10% discount
`>$2001 gives 20% discount

The trick is I need the given discount only to apply to the given interval.
(i.e. an order of $3000 would be $1000 + $900 + $800)

Is there a way to do this with a formula or in Visual Basic?

I have been unable to find a question like this, but please let me know if there is one.

Comment: How about this one [Tiered Discount](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/154151-tiered-discounts.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just three tiers this simple Nested IF will work:

```
=IF(A1>1000,1000+IF(A1>2000,900+(A1-2000)*0.8,(A1-1000)*0.9),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim MyVal as Long
Dim Discount as Long
MyVal = Range("A1").value

If MyVal >= 0 AND MyVal <=1000 Then
    'Do Nothing
EndIf
If MyVal >= 1001 AND MyVal <=2000 Then
    Discount = MyVal * .1
    MyVal = MyVal - Discount
EndIf
If MyVal >=2001 Then
    Discount = MyVal * .2
    MyVal = MyVal - Discount
EndIf

Msgbox MyVal
```